# Не знаю как получить индекс из списка кнопок C# winForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Пишу код программы для создания графов из теории графов.

При нажатии на сетку генерируется узел графа с соответствующим индексом. Справа генерируются кнопки. Я хочу, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку узлы связывались ребром. Например, при нажатии на кнопку на 1 строке и 2 колонке будет рисоваться ребро, соединяющее 1 и 2 окружности.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код для генерации кнопок

```
 List<Button> btnList = new List<Button>();
for (int z = 1; z <= count; z++)
                {
                    for (int x = 1; x <= count; x++)
                    {
                        Button btn = new Button();
                        btn.Text = 0.ToString();
                        btn.Location = new Point(z*30, x*30);
                        btn.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 30);
                        btn.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                        btn.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(btnClick);
                        panel1.Controls.Add(btn);
                        btnList.Add(btn);
                    }
                }
```

Код события, описывающего нажатия кнопку

```
public void btnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = (Button)sender;
            button.Text = (int.Parse(button.Text)+1).ToString();

            

            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black);
            //g.DrawLine(pen, );
            //g.DrawLine(pen, );
            pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
        }
```

Может быть вопрос очень глупый, но я не понимаю на обратиться в функции btnClick к индексам нажатой кнопки.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `btn.Location = new Point(z*30, x*30);` => `z = btn.Location.X/30; x = btn.Location.Y/30`

Comment: ты можешь попробовать использовать TabIndex

Answer (score 0):

Для передачи каких-то параметров в событие можешь использовать:

```
button.Click += (sender, e) => ButtonClickEvent(sender, e, ...);

public void ButtonClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e, ...)
{

}
```

Либо, ты можешь какую-то информацию запихнуть в Tag кнопки и брать её оттуда.

Пример:

Нам нужно создать программно кнопки, которые выводили на экран "своё" сообщение. Мы делаем следующее:

```
for (int x = 1; x <= 10; x++)
{
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.Click += (sender, e) => ButtonClickEvent(sender, e, i);
}

public void ButtonClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e, int i) =>
    MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
```